# SQL Return Table with where clause and occurrences of value of total table

Tags: sql-server, count, where

I am stumped trying to figure out how to achieve this. I know how I would achieve it in C#, but not SQL.

Say I have the following table:

| ID | Name | RouteId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 1001 |
| 2 | Bob | 1002 |
| 3 | Ana | 1001 |
| 4 | Jim | 1001 |
| 5 | Eli | 1001 |

I would like to return the entire table, with an extra column showing the total occurrences of `routeID` by name, so `where name='Bob'` looks like:

| ID | Name | RouteId | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 1001 | 4 |
| 2 | Bob | 1002 | 1 |

However, if I write something like

```
declare @ct as nvarchar(5)
set @ct = (SELECT COUNT(RouteId) from <table>)

select *, @ct
from <table>
where name = 'Bob'
```

I get the total number of ALL route IDs, not just the one displayed in the row.

I tried looking into computed columns but from what I can see it doesn't support this type of query.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a windowed `COUNT` inside a derived table (subquery)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Total = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.RouteId)
    FROM MyTable t
) t
WHERE t.Name = 'Bob';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=714889db2d11ab04e62a2a2d4f1b72c2)

Answer (score 6):

Three more alternatives:

#### Subquery

```
SELECT 
    MT.*,
    Total =
        (
            SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
            FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT2
            WHERE
                MT2.RouteId = MT.RouteId
        )
FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT
WHERE 
    MT.[Name] = 'Bob';
```

#### Apply

```
SELECT 
    MT.*,
    A.Total
FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT
CROSS APPLY 
(
        SELECT Total = COUNT_BIG(*) 
        FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT2
        WHERE MT2.RouteId = MT.RouteID
        GROUP BY ()
) AS A
WHERE 
    MT.[Name] = 'Bob';
```

#### Join

```
SELECT 
    MT.*, 
    T.Total 
FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        MT2.RouteId, 
        Total = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS MT2
    GROUP BY MT2.RouteId
) AS T
    ON T.RouteId = MT.RouteId
WHERE
    MT.[Name] = 'Bob';
```

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe8a8aef56dcc7b39ac954031cca8943)